# RuntimeError: Matching Python module for ImageSensor not found

Tags: python, c++, ubuntu, nupic

I want to run this test:
https://github.com/numenta/htmresearch/tree/master/projects/image_test
But when I execute `python run_mnist_experiment.py`,I get an error:

```
    ERR:  Matching Python module for ImageSensor not found. [/root/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/NUP-CORE-NCRM/src/nupic/engine/RegionImplFactory.cpp line 444]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roy/PycharmProjects/htm/run_mnist_experiment.py", line 237, in <module>
    net = createNetwork()
  File "/home/roy/PycharmProjects/htm/run_mnist_experiment.py", line 98, in createNetwork
    json.dumps(DEFAULT_IMAGESENSOR_PARAMS))
  File "/home/roy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nupic/engine/__init__.py", line 639, in addRegion
    engine_internal.Network.addRegion(self, name, nodeType, nodeParams)
  File "/home/roy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nupic/bindings/engine_internal.py", line 1167, in addRegion
    return _engine_internal.Network_addRegion(self, *args, **kwargs)
RuntimeError: Matching Python module for ImageSensor not found.
```

So I execute `pip install ImageSensor`，but I got this：

```
Collecting ImageSensor
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ImageSensor (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for ImageSensor
```

What can I do to run this test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching on google and numenta repositories I found that this module can be found in nupic.vision. So you simply need to install that repo. [Here](https://discourse.numenta.org/t/mnist-test-problem/1153) is the source I've found on google. Simply use that to solve your problem.

The module itself can be found there: https://github.com/numenta/nupic.vision/blob/master/src/nupic/vision/regions/ImageSensor.py

Comment: This helps me a lot! Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure :) you can mark the question as resolved then by tiking my answer.